# How to add a margin top when image is rotating with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, margin

I want to add margin to the top of the image when it is rotated by 90 degrees. This is how I rotate the image:

```
const img = document.querySelector("#mocci-logo")

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  if(!window.scrollY) {
    img.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
  } else {
    img.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)"
  }
})
```

I know it's might be simple, but I'm a beginner. So hopefully someone could show me how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `img.style.marginTop = "40px";`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Yeah, but how do I implement this properly into the existing code?

Comment: Can you share the HTML/CSS also so I can show you properly

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I made this via elementor, so the code is really trashy. Can't you show me how to put that in the existing javascript code?

Comment: So you want the margin on scroll  or normally!

Comment: Only on scroll @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: I have added an answer, try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const img = document.querySelector("#mocci-logo")

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  if(!window.scrollY) {
    img.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
    img.style.marginTop = "0px"; // This can also be 0 or "0".
  } else {
    img.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)"
    img.style.marginTop = "60px";
  }
})
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks Manas! But the issue now is, if I'm scrolling back to the top the logo sticks at this margin (60px) and don't go back to the starting position?

Comment: @leon_505 You need to add img.style.marginTop = "0"; to the first IF block.

Comment: @leon_505 Just a helpful note, when you have a value of 0 in css, you can either denote it with a unit or without. So 0px and 0 are treated the same way.

Comment: @leon_505 I know, just didn't wanted to confuse OP so i did `"0px"`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I figured =) No worries! He will probably come across that pretty quickly, so I wanted to mention it.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal thank you so much Manas. :) I really appreciate your time and help! Now everything works, but the animation itself is a little bit buggy and falters. When I scroll down the logo falters for a short time and then the transition becomes clean.. :D

Comment: @leon_505 Can you share a link to me of your website!

Comment: I made the transition via css and referred to the logo id: #mocci-logo {
    transition: 0.25s ease;
}

Comment: I wish I could do that but I signed a NDA so I can't, sorry :( @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: The transition itself works fine but as mentioned not really clean at the beginning. It happens only at the beginning when I start scrolling down. @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: @leon_505 You can share somewhere else, you can trust me. If you don't want to no problem just, just share the Elementor HTML and your CSS / javascript

Comment: Do you have an email address or another contact where I can reach you out? @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: @leon_505 On my profile... https://stackoverflow.com/users/11171286/manas-khandelwal

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Awesome I'll contact you there! :)